# Missing pointer in HoloLens 2 Emulator

Tags: emulation, hololens

my **pointer** disappeared.

How it looks now:

[image]

I have been using the HoloLens 2 Emulator for some time, everything worked, but after a certain moment the indicator for controlling the virtual environment disappeared and it is now impossible to work with it.

Does anyone know what affects whether the pointer appears or disappears?

You can see the pointer on the picture on this Microsoft page:
[Using the HoloLens Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-hololens-emulator)

I tried all switches in settings.

I tried uninstal + instal emulator again.

I tried older emulator image.

Comment: Can check if VPN is interfering.  Here is a note that may help explain:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-hololens-emulator#troubleshooting      "If Hololens2 Emulator doesn't respond to input from your keyboard or mouse, try disabling your VPN connection."

Answer (score 0):

Finally!
I found where the problem is, it's very st...d.

If you use in setting: "Sign in with Microsoft Account" and restart the Emulator, than it will starts without pointer!
(It is easy to reproduce it.)

[Sign in with Microsoft Account - ON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHYZL.png)

I was expecting some benefit from logging in, instead I ran into this limitation. :-(

[Sign in with Microsoft Account - OFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By7sJ.png)